# Access Knockout Function from External Function

Tags: knockout.js

There's a few similar questions relating to what I'm after, but I haven't found any related specifically to my issue.

I'm using Knockout with success throughout the website I'm building, however, have come up against a brick wall when trying to access a ViewModel function from an externally hosted function, of which I have no control over, with various callback attributes.

```
Checkout.showLightbox();
```

The Checkout Lightbox functionality is handled by the below script:

```
<script src="paymentwebsite"
                data-error="errorCallback"
                data-cancel="cancelCallback"
                data-complete="completeCallback"
                data-beforeRedirect="beforeRedirect"
                data-afterRedirect="afterRedirect">
            </script>

    function completeCallback() {
        //A View Model Function or,
        //Use as validation before Knockout Submit binding

    }
```

The function shown above (completeCallback) - called via the attributes of the external JS file - is received after the form submission of which they are called.  I have 2 options:

1. This function somehow completes prior to and returns true, for Knockout's submit binding, or,
2. This function calls a View Model function, albiet without form data.

The problem is, I am unaware of a way that I can call a function within the View Model, or pause the form submit binding until this non-Knockout function is complete.

Comment: It might work to notify on a public subscribable in your complete callback, and have your viewmodel subscribe to it. http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html